# Are Indians immune to Israeli stink bombs?

Tags: physiology, india, israel

Russian Television network, RT [report](https://www.rt.com/news/397724-israeli-stink-bombs-india/) that:

> An Israeli crowd control stink bomb known as the Skunk, which smells like raw sewage and rotting bodies, destined for employment in the restive region of Kashmir, was rejected after it was found that Indians easily ignored its smell, local media report.

I am unsure about the veracity of the article. Googling for it, I get results in lots of newspaper, but I'm in doubt whether to take it seriously or not.

Can someone shed light on this?

Comment: Is this intended to jerk an ethnic reaction or a fake news check or are you doing headline research for the National Enquirer